# How use a DTO for display a table in html with JSP and JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm new in JSP, I'm learning to use the pattern design DTO for display data in a table JSP with JSTL. This is my class DTO:

```
package Driver;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class DTO{
public abstract DTO load(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;
public abstract String toString();

Consultas con = new Consultas();
}
```

And this is my code for the class CostumerCost:

```
package Driver;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ClienteCosto extends DTO {
public int idcliente;
public String nombre;
public double enero;
public double febrero;
public double marzo;
public double abril;
public double mayo;
public double junio;
public double julio;
public double agosto;
public double septiembre;
public double octubre;
public double noviembre;
public double diciembre;

public ClienteCosto(){
   super();
}
public double getEnero() {
return enero;
}
public void setEnero(double enero) {
this.enero = enero;
}
public double getFebrero() {
return febrero;
}
public void setFebrero(double febrero) {
this.febrero = febrero;
}
public double getMarzo() {
return marzo;
}
public void setMarzo(double marzo) {
this.marzo = marzo;
}
public double getAbril() {
return abril;
}
public void setAbril(double abril) {
this.abril = abril;
}
public double getMayo() {
return mayo;
}
public void setMayo(double mayo) {
this.mayo = mayo;
}
public double getJunio() {
return junio;
}
public void setJunio(double junio) {
this.junio = junio;
}
public double getJulio() {
return julio;
}
public void setJulio(double julio) {
this.julio = julio;
}
public double getAgosto() {
return agosto;
}
public void setAgosto(double agosto) {
this.agosto = agosto;
}
public double getSeptiembre() {
return septiembre;
}
public void setSeptiembre(double septiembre) {
this.septiembre = septiembre;
}
public double getOctubre() {
return octubre;
}
public void setOctubre(double octubre) {
this.octubre = octubre;
}
public double getNoviembre() {
return noviembre;
}
public void setNoviembre(double noviembre) {
this.noviembre = noviembre;
}
public double getDiciembre() {
return diciembre;
}
public void setDiciembre(double diciembre) {
this.diciembre = diciembre;
}
public int getIdcliente(){
return idcliente;
}
public void setIdcliente(int idcliente) {
this.idcliente = idcliente;
}

public String getNombre() {
return nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String toString(){
return(
        "<tr>"
        +"<td>"+nombre+"</td>"
        +"<td>"+enero+ "</td>"
        +"</tr>");
}
public DTO load(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{
ClienteCosto clientecosto = new ClienteCosto();
clientecosto.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
clientecosto.setEnero(rs.getDouble("enero"));
return clientecosto;
}
}
```

This is my code for the query, this code is in package Driver and class consultas.

```
public List<ClienteCosto> list() throws SQLException{
List<ClienteCosto> clientCost = new ArrayList<ClienteCosto>();
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null; 
try{
    //connection = getConexion().getConnection();
    String query = "select idcliente,"
        + "nombre,sum(case when month (fecha)=1 then costo else 0 end) as enero,"
        + "from actividad "
        + "inner join cliente "
        + "on actividad.cliente_idcliente=cliente.idcliente "
        + "where year(fecha)=2016 group by idcliente;";
   st = getConexion().createStatement();
   rs = st.executeQuery(query);
   while(rs.next()){
       ClienteCosto cliente = new ClienteCosto();
       cliente.setIdcliente(rs.getInt("idcliente"));
       cliente.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
       cliente.setEnero(rs.getDouble("enero"));
       clientCost.add(cliente);
   }
  }finally{
      if(rs != null)try{ 
          rs.close();}catch(SQLException e){}
  }
   return clientCost;
  }
```

Finally I use JSTL in my JSP but I dont know how use it:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
                <table>
                    <c:forEach items="${clientecosto}" var="clientecost">
                    <tr>
                         <td>${clientecost.idcliente}</td>
                         <td><c:out value="${clientecost.nombre}"/></td>
                         <td><c:out value="${clientecost.enero}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    </c:forEach>            
                </table>
```

This my code from servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        List<ClienteCosto> clientecosto = clientecostoDTO.list();
        request.setAttribute("clientecosto", clientecosto);
               request.getRequestDispatcher("/WebContent/main.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }catch (SQLException e){
        throw new ServletException("no se puede realizar query");
    }


}
```

Comment: This looks good.  In your servlet's `doGet` you will need to add `clientCost` to your `request` named as `clientecosto`

Comment: Show your relevant servlet code i.e. the `doGet` method

Comment: yes, ready @scary

Comment: This code looks OK - what exactly is happening?

Comment: I think the query must be instantiated somewhere.In my class DTO I don't call it, it's correct?

Comment: in my JSP dont display the table....

Comment: any errors in you web server log?

Comment: No, it's running correctly.